# Slow MySQL query speed

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization

I have a problem with MySQL query performance. Please look at the details below. My question is if perhaps my schema could be simplified? This has to be done keeping generic device type support - please see below.

I'm creating a MySQL database for device data storage. I assumed that the devices are generic and they could be a ds18b20 temperature sensor or a solar inverter device that provides voltage, current values etc.

I'm going to gather temperature data and power (ac/dc) data. Temperature data is logged every 2 minutes. Power data is logged every 30 seconds (from 7 AM to 6 PM (on average)).

Also there is a user table to provide possibility to log another device configuration.

My schema is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name CHAR(100) UNIQUE,
    email CHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    user_hash CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    server_hash CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE devices(
    device_id TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    dev_name CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    dev_type TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id),
    KEY(dev_type),
    UNIQUE (user_id, dev_type, dev_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE data_logs (
    data_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    dev_type TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    insert_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    readout_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (data_id, dev_type, readout_time),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dev_type) REFERENCES devices (dev_type),
    UNIQUE(dev_type, readout_time),
    INDEX (readout_time)
);

CREATE TABLE power_data_readings(
    data_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    device_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ac_power DECIMAL(4,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    dc_voltage DECIMAL(5,1) UNSIGNED,
    dc_current DECIMAL(3,1) UNSIGNED,
    cpu_temperature DECIMAL(4,1),
    radiator_temperature DECIMAL(4,1),
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id, data_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES data_logs (data_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices (device_id)
);

CREATE TABLE temperature_data_readings(
    data_id INT UNSIGNED,
    device_id TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    temperature DECIMAL(4,1),
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id, data_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES data_logs (data_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES devices (device_id)
);

ALTER TABLE data_logs ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
ALTER TABLE power_data_readings ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
ALTER TABLE temperature_data_readings ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;


CREATE VIEW view_power_logs AS
SELECT L.readout_time, D.dev_name, P.ac_power, P.dc_current, P.dc_voltage, P.cpu_temperature, P.radiator_temperature FROM power_data_readings P
    LEFT JOIN data_logs L on (L.data_id = P.data_id)
    LEFT JOIN devices D on (D.device_id = P.device_id);

CREATE VIEW view_temperature_logs AS
SELECT L.readout_time, D.dev_name, T.temperature FROM temperature_data_readings T
    LEFT JOIN data_logs L on (L.data_id = T.data_id)
    LEFT JOIN devices D on (D.device_id = T.device_id);

CREATE VIEW view_user_data AS
SELECT D.dev_name, D.device_id, U.user_name, U.user_id FROM users U 
    LEFT JOIN devices D on (D.user_id = U.user_id);
```

The problem is for example with this query which only returns results after 30 seconds.

```
SELECT 
  date_format(readout_time, '%Y-%m-01') AS Month, 
  ROUND(SUM(ac_power) / 120 / 1000, 2) AS kWh  
FROM 
  view_power_logs GROUP BY date_format(readout_time,   '%Y-%m-01');
```

Result:

```
+------------+---------+  
| Month      | kWh     |  
+------------+---------+  
| 2017-06-01 |  430.62 |  
| 2017-07-01 |  831.27 |  
| 2017-08-01 |  759.18 |  
| 2017-09-01 |  412.86 |  
| 2017-10-01 |  306.46 |  
| 2017-11-01 |  137.95 |  
| 2017-12-01 |   75.81 |  
| 2018-01-01 |  120.10 |  
| 2018-02-01 |  193.46 |  
| 2018-03-01 |  353.71 |  
| 2018-04-01 |  790.14 |  
| 2018-05-01 |  941.57 |  
| 2018-06-01 |  811.76 |  
| 2018-07-01 |  848.74 |  
| 2018-08-01 |  807.26 |  
| 2018-09-01 |  629.24 |  
| 2018-10-01 |  395.99 |  
| 2018-11-01 |  174.35 |  
| 2018-12-01 |   38.61 |  
| 2019-01-01 |   61.77 |  
| 2019-02-01 |  303.78 |  
| 2019-03-01 |  454.29 |  
| 2019-04-01 |  719.70 |  
| 2019-05-01 |  684.94 |  
| 2019-06-01 | 1012.43 |  
| 2019-07-01 |  809.48 |  
| 2019-08-01 |  799.86 |  
| 2019-09-01 |  571.30 |  
| 2019-10-01 |  468.15 |  
| 2019-11-01 |  139.32 |  
| 2020-01-01 |   19.98 |  
+------------+---------+  
31 rows in set (31,57 sec)
```

I'm thinking of adding events that update additional summary tables for statistics queries but maybe there is better solution?

Or maybe there is a better approach than MySQL?

Please don't hesitate to ask for details if needed.

Comment: it would be better to keep readout_time in power_data_readings table,this way you eliminate extra join and aslo you could create generated virtual column for expression from your group by, after that you can create index on (month, ac_power)

Comment: How many records in each table? What is the machine spec (CPU, RAM, disk configuration)? Why do you have `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`? With HDD prices the way they are, you are trading performance for space - is this really necessary?

Comment: How many devices are you planning to support?  If Amazon wants to adopt your solution, how many vehicles do you think they will want this sensor installed on - just in the US only for temperature sensing?  If you ever hope to go BIG, you must plan big.  Remove the COMPRESSED rows and do nothing else and see how long it takes to complete your existing 30 second query to have an appreciation of Verace's perspective.  We need to talk, view my profile, Network profile, please.

Comment: @Vérace why do you say he is trading performance for space? if there is a lot of data which doesn't fit to RAM then read smaller amount and decompress it may work faster than read ten times more of uncompressed data (the same thoughts are related to writes)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. Regarding ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, I have added it to decrease DB size indeed, and as far as I remember it did not affect performance. I don't have a plan to go big, but I wanted to have generic solution for future. For now I have two solar inverter (3.3+3.3 kW), but maybe I will add another one or two in the future... Regarding temperature sensors for now I have 4. Two of them are for monitoring central heating stove. And yes, in that case having user table for multiple configuration is pointless, but I wanted to have it for potential needs...

Comment: Also I'm going to add another device type: Particulate Matter sensor for air purity data monitoring. I will try to adopt @Nikita suggestions to my schema. Thank you. I will check again if COMPRESSED format impacts performance in my case.